# How to find newest matching pattern file in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to copy only files which are latest version in Bash.

For example in my below script I am copying all the files but now I need to copy the latest version (the latest version will be given as the last param in the filename).

Examples of my file names:

```
AAA_BBB_CCC_1
AAA_BBB_CCC_2  # I need to copy this file instead the above one because it has
               # _2 which means it is the latest version.

BBB_CCC_DDD_1
BBB_CCC_DDD_2  # I need to copy this file
```

Comment: There's about a million tools that handle dealing with versioned files or smart directory structure updates, why not use one of those? (A version control system, `rsync`...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm lazy so I'd use Perl for this.  Working on the basis of 'the version is an underscore followed by digits at the end of the name', you could use this to read one file per line as input, and generate just the latest version of each file in the output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %files;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    my($base, $vrsn) = m/(.*)_(\d+)$/;
    $files{$base} //= $vrsn;    # Set if not yet defined
    $files{$base}   = $vrsn if ($vrsn > $files{$base});
}

foreach my $base (sort keys %files)
{
    print "${base}_$files{$base}\n";
}
```

You can fit this into your pipeline wherever you need it.

Comment: Thank you so much will try to fit this inmy application

Comment: `$base` is the part of the name prior to the version number, the base part of the name; `$vrsn` is the version number, the number after the final underscore.  Using your `AAA_BBB_CCC_1` example name, `($base eq "AAA_BBB_CCC" && $vrsn eq "1")` evaluates to true.